# Match sequence of words with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings and I want to extract from it only the item name, with spaces, if there are.

The strings stay in column named `0`, and index is just for reference.

For example, from each index line I want the following results:

**Index - Expected result**

0 - BOV BCONTRA

1 - BF PARAROLE C

2 - CUBINHOS DACE

... and so on.

Notice that inline 25 the desired result are **not separated** from the preceding numbers with **spaces**

There can be a dot `.` between the words line in index line 30.

I've tried `re.findall(r"\n\d{1,2} \d+(\b\w+\b)")` with no success.

Also `re.findall(r"\n\d{1,2} \d+( ?\w+)")` brings me only the first word, and I want all the words, not only the first one.

The lines start with a `\n` char that it's not printed at the list.

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample input as text, not image of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so basically you need all the upper case strings on the text.
try this expression, where it will get all the text with or without spaces

```
re.findall('[A-Z]+[ A-Z]*', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want `[A-Z .]+`, not "words" (represented by `r'\w'`), bordered by
integers. [`\w` maps to
`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

That's the Regex string to have: `r'\d+ \d+([A-Z .]+)\d+'`.

I don't know what you mean that a newline precedes each line. If you have a string with lines in it, it's perhaps better to split the input in lines with `string.splitlines()`, then do a linear Regex match (`re.match` so the Regex only matches from the start) on each relevant line.